# Access state inside a function to dynamically set drawer width

Tags: reactjs, react-native, navigation-drawer

I want to dynamically change the drawer width when the device orientation changes. This is my code

```
updateWidth = (width) => {
    this.setState({drawerWidth: width/2 });
  }
```

I call updateWidth when `componentDidMount` and `onLayout` functions are called.

In the `drawerNavigator` declaration, I set `drawerWidth: this.state.drawerWidth` . Here I get an error telling me that `drawerWidth: this.state.drawerWidth`  is undefined. How can I solve this issue?

**Edit:**
This is the component code overview

```
const { width } = Dimensions.get('window');

const AppDrawer = DrawerNavigator(
{
  Category: {
    path: '/bla',
    screen: bla,
  },
},
{
  drawerWidth: this.state.drawerWidth ,
  contentComponent: test,
  initialRouteName: 'tets',
  contentOptions: {
    activeTintColor: '#fd67d3',
  },
}
);


const AppNavigator = StackNavigator({
...
})


class RootContainer extends Component {
 constructor(props) {
  super(props);
  this.state = {
      drawerWidth: 30
  }
}

  onLayout(e) {
    const {width, height} = Dimensions.get('window')
    this.updateWidth(width);
  }

  updateWidth = (width) => {
    this.setState({drawerWidth: width/2 });
  }

  componentDidMount() {
    this.updateWidth(width);
}
```

Comment: Are you using a stateless component ? And could you provide more code of your component ?

Comment: @TimH I added more code

Answer (score 0):

Your drawer component is a stateless component. Recreate it as a class based component and then you can have state in it. Stateless components can only grab props passed down to them, but they can not store any state.

Comment: I am new on react and all the tutorial I showed was creating the drawer this way. How can you show me how to make it stateful?

Comment: @user567 TimH posted the correct answer. You need to experiment with it. His answer shows you how to make a class component properly and init state.

Answer (score 0):

You need to initialize your state in the constructor and use a stateful component.

```
class AppDrawer extends Component {
  constructor(props) {
      super(props);
      this.state = {
          drawerWidth: 0 //or any other number
      }
  }
```

Comment: Have you tried to create a constructor in your RootContainer Component ?

Comment: can you try to update your state directly from onLayout and componentDidMount ?